# how to join features columns of two LabeledPoints in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two `LabeledPoints` - `lable1` and `label2`:

```
label1 = (label,[feature1,feature2,feature3])
label2 = (label,[feature4,feature5])
```

The `label` column in both `LabeledPoints` is same and I want to form a new `LabeledPoint` which has `feature` columns from the two `LabeledPoints` joined together:

```
label_new = (label,[feature1,feature2,feature3,feature4,feature5])
```

How can I add the two `LabeledPoints` together?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [LabeledPoint](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=labeledpoint#pyspark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint) documentation for `PySpark`, a `LabeledPoint` object has two attributes `label` and `features`, therefore we can use the `features` attribute to achieve this.

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
import numpy as np

a = LabeledPoint(0, [1,2,3])
b = LabeledPoint(0, [3,1,2])
c = LabeledPoint(a.label, np.concatenate((a.features, b.features), axis=0))

print c # LabeledPoint(0.0, [1.0,2.0,3.0,3.0,1.0,2.0])
```

Note, you must be careful about the label values! they might differ.